# Firebase Phone Auth Daily limit per mobile number

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I wanted to use firebase phone auth for the second level of authorization, I am not using this for mobile OTP verification, instead, if the customer logged via email/password will get one more step to enter the OTP received, so each day if the customer signed in multiple time we may have to send OTP multiple times to the same mobile number.

So do we have any limitations here how many OTP can be sent to the same mobile number per day?

Comment: Not hard to test this theory, I think?

Comment: Does https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits have the answers you require?

Comment: @SiHa No, Its not conveying anything related to this, According to them they have limitations on how many OTP per minute, but how many OTP per minute per mobile number is not mentioned anywhere.